# pandoc lists in environments

Tags: itemize, conversion, pandoc

I want to put a list in the `lemma` environment. I am using pandoc to convert from markdown to LaTeX, so I thought it would be neat to use markdown lists. I tried:

```
\begin{lemma}
The following are equivalent:

- the moon is made out of cheese
- the axiom of choice

\end{lemma}
```

But this does not result in an `itemize`. By removing the `\begin` command, it does result in an itemize (you can see that [here](http://tinyurl.com/p33ehs7)). Of course, one of the fixes is to use the LaTeX `itemize` environment, but I prefer the compact markdown syntax. Are there any workarounds / options / filters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a header file (say `header.tex`) that contains the following

```
\let\otherbegin\begin
\let\otherend\end
```

Then include a header file (either using `-H` or `--include-in-header`, or via `--include-before-body=header.tex`). This should allow you to use

```
\otherbegin{lemma}
The following are equivalent

- the moon is made out of cheese
- the axiom of choice

\otherend{lemma}
```

This should [convert via Pandoc](http://goo.gl/8nKcIy) to

```
\otherbegin{lemma} The following are equivalent

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  the moon is made out of cheese
\item
  the axiom of choice
\end{itemize}

\otherend{lemma}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use raw LaTeX blocks.

```markdown
`\begin{lemma}`{=latex}
The following are equivalent:

- the moon is made out of cheese
- the axiom of choice
`\end{lemma}`{=latex}
```